# Errors Migrating from Angular 2 to 4.0.0

Tags: angular

(Edited question) After upgrading the packages and dependencies,

```
"typescript": "2.1.1"
"typings": "^0.8.1"
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
"rxjs": "5.0.1"
```

Using the upgrade command to upgrade angular packages to 4.0.0 did not help. I am doing the usual `npm run clean` , `npm install` and `npm run build` in the same order. Should I change the version of typings?

```
ERROR in [default] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts:15:47
Cannot find name 'Iterable'.


ERROR in [default] /typings/browser/ambient/node/index.d.ts:426:10
Interface 'NodeBuffer' incorrectly extends interface 'Uint8Array'.
  Types of property 'fill' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: any, offset?: number, end?: number) => Buffer' is not assignable to type '(value: number, start?: number, end?: number) => this'.
      Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'this'.
```

Comment: delete 'node_modules' folder. Run 'npm cache clean' and then run npm install as administrator.

Comment: I tried with that, did not help. I then downgraded typescript to 2.1.1 and the first error is gone. But I still see the error `Cannot find name 'Iterable' ` and the `Uint8Array`

Comment: Try typescript ~2.2.0

Comment: Run tsc -v through cmd to check version

Comment: @TechFreak With typescript ~2.2.0, I get additional errors `/node_modules/bootstrap-loader/loader.js' has unsupported extension. The only supported extensions are '.ts', '.tsx', '.d.ts'.`

Comment: @TechFreak tsc version 2.0.3

Comment: You should get 2.2.0. Downgrading will not help. Install typescript globally. npm install -g typescript@latest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139535/discussion-between-techfreak-and-user3344978).

Answer (score 0):

Update your package as below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

add the below to tsconfig.json, inside compipleroptions

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "skipLibCheck": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of the suggestions by other users. Here's how i finally resolved/eliminated the errors:

1. Started with incremental upgrade from 2.0.0 all the way to 2.4.10, changing only the versions of angular
2. Next started with upgrade from 2.4.0 to 4.0.0-beta.6 where I encountered the first error :
   `ERROR in [default] node_modules/@angular/core/src/change_detection/differs/iterable_differs.d.ts:15:47
   Cannot find name 'Iterable'.`

To resolve this, I installed typings.core-js through `typings install dt~core-js --global --save`, then proceeded to add `/// <reference path="../typings/index.d.ts" />` at the top of `main.ts`. This eliminated the issue with `Iterable`

3. At the end of upgrading to 4.0.0, I tried to upgrade Typescript to `^2.1.5`, but it gave a lot of errors, so I downgraded to `2.0.3` (read in one of angular issues) which helped me to run `npm install` and `npm run build` successfully.
4. Since I was still using `typings/ambient`, I came across [this](http://brianflove.com/2016/07/19/upgrading-to-typings-1-x/) article about upgrading to typings 1.x. I re-installed typings with the right versions and finally was able to build successfully
5. But I saw `routes` errors in the console, because I hadnt previously mentioned `pathMatch: 'full'` in my routes. Once i included the `pathMatch` field, I got the application to run properly.